# How to vectorize matrix whose index is matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, lookup, vectorization

I have two for-loops embedded in a code that is repeated many times. I want to speed things up:

```
for i = 1:10
 for j = 1:10
  A(i,j) = B(i,j,D(i,j))*C(i,j); 
 end 
end
```

Here D consist of integers which are indices to B. Without dependence on D the for-loops could be replaced by a elementwise matrix multiplication. 
The problem is how to evaluate B in an elegant way. I searched SO and mathworks-pages and tried linear indexing, but this produces errors:

```
d = reshape(D, 100, []);
b = reshape(B, 100, []);
arrayfun(@(x) b(x,d(x)), 1:100);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to replace the two for-loops?

Comment: The problem is not only evaluating `B` in an elegant way, you are overwriting `A` all the time which means that the only result you will get is the last layer, i.e. when `i=10` and `j=´10`

Comment: @OlegKomarov Thanks for commenting! My code is actually okay and does what it was supposed to do: Creating element-wise a Matrix `A` by multiplying elements of `B` and `C`. The tricky part is looking up indexes from `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform `D` into a linear index:

```
[rows,cols]=ndgrid(1:10,1:10);
idx = sub2ind(size(B),rows(:),cols(:),D(:));

A = zeros(10,10); %# initialize A to the right size
A(:) = B(idx).*C(:);
```

Comment: Great! Your code snippet led my to a solution which runs significantly faster than my for-loops. Since `B` is a three dimensional array, your second line of code has to be `idx = sub2ind(size(B),rows(:),cols(:),D(:));` Thanks!

Comment: @BQ92-PwDD3: I fixed the solution. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use elementwise multiplication of `B` against the layers in `A` ordered by the indices in `D` (note that you are looping first along rows, then columns, which means you go right to the end of the row, then to the next row etc... that is why I transpose and reshape into column `D`).

An easy way is to use `bsxfun()`:

```
out = bsxfun(@times, A(:,:,reshape(D',[],1)), B);
```

where each layer of out is:

```
out(:,:,1)   = A(:,:,D(1,1)).*B(:,:)
out(:,:,2)   = A(:,:,D(1,2)).*B(:,:)
...
out(:,:,ncols*(i-1) + j) = A(:,:,D(i,j)).*B(:,:)
```

If this is not what you wanted, my bad. I will delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. There is a confusion of variables. Besides that, I could not figure out how the suggestion would solve the problem...